# Generate a nested JSON

Tags: sql, node.js, json, nested, mariadb

I'm trying to generate a nested JSON from a simple JSON. But I can find a solution.

This is the JSON that I try to convert:

```json
[
  {
    "station_id": "ESP0001",
    "datetime": "2022-11-25T06:43:06.000Z",
    "dimension": "temperature",
    "value": 15.33,
    "representation": "°C",
    "unit": "Celsius",
    "unit_id": 1
  },
  {
    "station_id": "ESP0001",
    "datetime": "2022-11-25T06:43:06.000Z",
    "dimension": "humidity",
    "value": 92,
    "representation": "%",
    "unit": "Percentage",
    "unit_id": 4
  },
  {
    "station_id": "ESP0001",
    "datetime": "2022-11-25T06:43:06.000Z",
    "dimension": "pressure",
    "value": 1016,
    "representation": "hPa",
    "unit": "HectoPascal",
    "unit_id": 5
  }
]
```

The data is given by this sql query (on MariaDB 10.8.):

```sql
SELECT  
    r.station_id, 
    r.datetime,
    ud.dimension,
    r.value,
    u.representation,
    u.unit,
    r.unit_id
FROM readings r 
INNER JOIN units u ON (u.id = r.unit_id) 
INNER JOIN unit_dimension ud ON (ud.id=u.dimension_id)
WHERE r.station_id = 'ESP0001'
AND r.datetime >= (
    SELECT max(datetime) 
    FROM readings r2 
    WHERE r2.unit_id = r.unit_id)
ORDER BY r.`datetime` DESC, u.id;
```

This is the desired JSON structure:

```json
[
  {
    "station_id": "ESP0001",
    "datetime": "2022-11-25T06:43:06.000Z",
    "readings": [
      {
        "dimension": "temperature",
        "value": 15.33,
        "representation": "°C",
        "unit": "Celsius",
        "unit_id": 1
      },
      {
        "dimension": "humidity",
        "value": 92,
        "representation": "%",
        "unit": "Percentage",
        "unit_id": 4
      },
      {
        "dimension": "pressure",
        "value": 1016,
        "representation": "hPa",
        "unit": "HectoPascal",
        "unit_id": 5
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This are the tables of de database:

- Units_dimension.
- Units.
- Readings.

Units_dimension table:

| id | dimension |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | temperature |
| 2 | humidity |
| 3 | pressure |

Units table:

| id | dimension_id | unit | representation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Celsius | °C |
| 2 | 1 | Farenheit | °F |
| 3 | 1 | Kelvin | K |
| 4 | 2 | Percentage | % |
| 5 | 3 | HectoPascal | hPa |

Readings table:

| id | station_id | datetime | unit_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ESP0001 | 2022-10-31 01:00:00.000 | 1 | 23.5 |
| 2 | ESP0001 | 2022-10-31 01:00:00.000 | 4 | 79 |
| 3 | ESP0001 | 2022-10-31 01:00:00.000 | 5 | 1019.6 |
| 4 | ESP0001 | 2022-10-31 02:00:00.000 | 1 | 23.3 |
| 5 | ESP0001 | 2022-10-31 02:00:00.000 | 4 | 79 |
| 5 | ESP0001 | 2022-10-31 02:00:00.000 | 5 | 1019.6 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

The backend uses Nodejs.

I tried to use JSON functions without a valid solution.

With this query:

```sql
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
    JSON_OBJECT(
        'station_id', station_id, 
        'dt', datetime,
        ud.dimension, value, 
        'representation', u.representation,
        'unit', u.unit 
    )
) AS readings
from readings r 
inner join units u on (u.id = r.unit_id)
inner join unit_dimension ud on (ud.id = u.dimension_id)
where station_id = 'ESP0001'
group by r.`datetime`
order by r.`datetime` desc, ud.id limit 1;
```

The result:

```json
[
   {"station_id": "ESP0001", "dt": "2022-11-25 07:43:06", "humidity": 92, "representation": "%", "unit": "Percentage"},
   {"station_id": "ESP0001", "dt": "2022-11-25 07:43:06", "temperature": 15.33, "representation": "°C", "unit": "Celsius"},
   {"station_id": "ESP0001", "dt": "2022-11-25 07:43:06", "pressure": 1016, "representation": "hPa", "unit": "HectoPascal"}
]
```

The only solution I can think of is to make two queries. One getting the last datetime and another to get the readings by station_id and datetime and make a mixed object.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

With @Ajax1234 solution query (I made some changes):

```sql
select json_arrayagg(
   json_object(
     "station_id", t.station_id, 
     "datetime", t.datetime, 
     "readings", t.js
   )
)as "read"
from (
  select 
    r.station_id, 
    r.datetime, 
    json_arrayagg(
      json_object(
        "dimension", ud.dimension, 
        "value", r.value, 
        "representation", u.representation, 
        "unit", u.unit, 
        "unit_id", r.unit_id
      )
    ) js 
   from readings r 
   left join units u on u.id = r.unit_id 
   left join unit_dimension ud on ud.id = u.dimension_id
   WHERE r.station_id = '${req.params.station_id}'
   group by r.station_id, r.datetime
   order by r.datetime DESC, r.unit_id ASC
   LIMIT 20
) t;
```

This is the result:

```json
[
  {
    "read": [
      {
        "station_id": "ESP0001",
        "datetime": "2022-11-28 02:08:46",
        "readings": [
          {
            "dimension": "temperature",
            "value": 12.65,
            "representation": "°C",
            "unit": "Celsius",
            "unit_id": 1
          },
          {
            "dimension": "humidity",
            "value": 79,
            "representation": "%",
            "unit": "Percentage",
            "unit_id": 4
          },
          {
            "dimension": "pressure",
            "value": 1017,
            "representation": "hPa",
            "unit": "HectoPascal",
            "unit_id": 5
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "station_id": "ESP0001",
        "datetime": "2022-11-28 01:58:46",
        "readings": [
          {
            "dimension": "pressure",
            "value": 1017,
            "representation": "hPa",
            "unit": "HectoPascal",
            "unit_id": 5
          },
          {
            "dimension": "humidity",
            "value": 78,
            "representation": "%",
            "unit": "Percentage",
            "unit_id": 4
          },
          {
            "dimension": "temperature",
            "value": 12.65,
            "representation": "°C",
            "unit": "Celsius",
            "unit_id": 1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "station_id": "ESP0001",
        "datetime": "2022-11-28 01:48:46",
        "readings": [
          {
            "dimension": "temperature",
            "value": 12.74,
            "representation": "°C",
            "unit": "Celsius",
            "unit_id": 1
          },
          {
            "dimension": "humidity",
            "value": 77,
            "representation": "%",
            "unit": "Percentage",
            "unit_id": 4
          },
          {
            "dimension": "pressure",
            "value": 1017,
            "representation": "hPa",
            "unit": "HectoPascal",
            "unit_id": 5
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "station_id": "ESP0001",
        "datetime": "2022-11-28 01:38:46",
        "readings": [
          {
            "dimension": "pressure",
            "value": 1017,
            "representation": "hPa",
            "unit": "HectoPascal",
            "unit_id": 5
          },
          {
            "dimension": "humidity",
            "value": 76,
            "representation": "%",
            "unit": "Percentage",
            "unit_id": 4
          },
          {
            "dimension": "temperature",
            "value": 12.93,
            "representation": "°C",
            "unit": "Celsius",
            "unit_id": 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Sometimes is doing the ASC order but other times is doing DESC order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create the `"readings"` key aggregation by grouping on the `station_id` and `datetime`, and then perform `json_arrayagg` again to build the final result:

```
select json_arrayagg(json_object("station_id", t.station_id, 
   "datetime", t.datetime, "readings", t.js)) 
from (select r.station_id, r.datetime, json_arrayagg(json_object("dimension", ud.dimension, 
      "value", r.value, 
      "representation", u.representation, 
      "unit", u.unit, "unit_id", u.id)) js 
      from readings r join units u on r.unit_id = u.id 
      join units_dimension ud on ud.id = u.dimension_id
group by r.station_id, r.datetime
order by r.datetime, r.unit_id) t
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bbwIjB9Q).

Also see [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eow21rSZ) for the same results, this time prettified with [`json_detailed`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_detailed/).

Comment: And i need to add some order by datetime and unit_id

Comment: is not working :( i tried with ud.id, u.id...

Comment: in my case with your edit is doing the ASC order un odd result but in even result is doing DESC order. I edit my post.