# Order By in JSON query mariadb

Tags: json, mariadb, sql-order-by

this question comes from [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74578642/generate-a-nested-json/74579123#74579123)

I want to order by datetime and I modified the query like this (that works):

```sql
select json_arrayagg(json_object("station_id", t.station_id, 
       "datetime", t.datetime, "readings", t.js)) 
from (select r.station_id, r.datetime, json_arrayagg(json_object("dimension", ud.dimension, 
      "value", r.value, 
      "representation", u.representation, 
      "unit", u.unit, "unit_id", u.id)) js 
      from readings r join units u on r.unit_id = u.id 
      join units_dimension ud on ud.id = u.dimension_id
group by r.station_id, r.datetime order by r.datetime desc) t
```

But if I add another field to order like u.id ASC (to make the same structure order of data readings, example order [temperature, humidity, pressure]) is not working properly on my DB. My DAB is mariadb 10.8 version.
I do this:

```sql
select json_arrayagg(json_object("station_id", t.station_id, 
   "datetime", t.datetime, "readings", t.js)) 
from (select r.station_id, r.datetime, json_arrayagg(json_object("dimension", ud.dimension, 
      "value", r.value, 
      "representation", u.representation, 
      "unit", u.unit, "unit_id", u.id)) js 
      from readings r join units u on r.unit_id = u.id 
      join units_dimension ud on ud.id = u.dimension_id
group by r.station_id, r.datetime order by r.datetime desc, u.id ASC) t
```

This is the resulset:

```json
[
  {
    "station_id": "ESP0001",
    "datetime": "2022-11-25 07:43:06",
    "readings": [
      {
        "dimension": "temperature",
        "value": 15.33,
        "representation": "°C",
        "unit": "Celsius",
        "unit_id": 1
      },
      {
        "dimension": "humidity",
        "value": 92,
        "representation": "%",
        "unit": "Percentage",
        "unit_id": 4
      },
      {
        "dimension": "pressure",
        "value": 1016,
        "representation": "hPa",
        "unit": "HectoPascal",
        "unit_id": 5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "station_id": "ESP0001",
    "datetime": "2022-11-25 07:33:06",
    "readings": [
      {
        "dimension": "temperature",
        "value": 15.3,
        "representation": "°C",
        "unit": "Celsius",
        "unit_id": 1
      },
      {
        "dimension": "humidity",
        "value": 92,
        "representation": "%",
        "unit": "Percentage",
        "unit_id": 4
      },
      {
        "dimension": "pressure",
        "value": 1016,
        "representation": "hPa",
        "unit": "HectoPascal",
        "unit_id": 5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "station_id": "ESP0001",
    "datetime": "2022-11-25 07:23:06",
    "readings": [
      {
        "dimension": "humidity",
        "value": 91,
        "representation": "%",
        "unit": "Percentage",
        "unit_id": 4
      },
      {
        "dimension": "pressure",
        "value": 1016,
        "representation": "hPa",
        "unit": "HectoPascal",
        "unit_id": 5
      },
      {
        "dimension": "temperature",
        "value": 15.43,
        "representation": "°C",
        "unit": "Celsius",
        "unit_id": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "station_id": "ESP0001",
    "datetime": "2022-11-25 07:13:06",
    "readings": [
      {
        "dimension": "pressure",
        "value": 1016,
        "representation": "hPa",
        "unit": "HectoPascal",
        "unit_id": 5
      },
      {
        "dimension": "temperature",
        "value": 15.46,
        "representation": "°C",
        "unit": "Celsius",
        "unit_id": 1
      },
      {
        "dimension": "humidity",
        "value": 91,
        "representation": "%",
        "unit": "Percentage",
        "unit_id": 4
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "station_id": "ESP0001",
    "datetime": "2022-11-25 07:03:05",
    "readings": [
      {
        "dimension": "temperature",
        "value": 14.78,
        "representation": "°C",
        "unit": "Celsius",
        "unit_id": 1
      },
      {
        "dimension": "humidity",
        "value": 98,
        "representation": "%",
        "unit": "Percentage",
        "unit_id": 4
      },
      {
        "dimension": "pressure",
        "value": 1017,
        "representation": "hPa",
        "unit": "HectoPascal",
        "unit_id": 5
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: To preserve the order of units couldn't you just order by `ud.id` before `u.id`?

Comment: Doesn' t work. :(